# Is there a way to find abusive user leaving comment with script using multiple accounts?

Tags: facebook

I am a facebook page admin and trying to host some question game with rewards to promote my page. The fastest 20 comments with correct answer will get prize.

I find that a few facebook users always able to answer quickly within the same time. I suspect they are using graph API with script to leave comment.

I tested and apparently the comment is indistinguishable with normal comment. ( expecting somewhat like comment via XXXX )

I know there is a way to distinguish, I had seen another page claiming they found abusers and deleted their comments.
Is there a button somewhere to get more detailed post comment data like ip address or comment via XXX? Or will reporting facebook help?

Comment: did you try safego ? https://apps.facebook.com/bd-safego/

Comment: Isnt safego a app to avoid some malware link? I am a page admin and I guess only official way to get detailed data will help me in this case. Its not a kind of content spam or scum.

Comment: http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/can-somebody-track-ip-address-facebook-through-phone-33395.html you can't track ip addresses directly

Comment: Thanks for helping. As of my experience, I believe there is way other than ip address to distinguish them